# Access logs for S3 signed URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have an app which generates temporary S3 signed URLs. I have access logging enabled for my S3 bucket but i don't see access logs when i download the object using signed URLs. Don't these show up in access logs?

Comment: Yes, they do show up in access logs... although the entire query string from the signed URL doesn't show.  Is that what you were expecting?

Comment: Yes, they do show up. Was a mistake on my end.

Answer (score 0):

They do show up. Found it the hard way. You can also use Amazon Athena to query data in S3 using SQL.